# Date conversion from string to unixepoch in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, flask

I'm using Flask to display dates and temperatures on page. Data is stored in SQLite database. It is working good with date and time as string but I have problem when I'm trying to convert date and time to unix epoch.

Python code:

```
cur = db.execute('select date,temperature from temperatures where temperatures.date > datetime(\'now\',\'-1hour\', \'localtime\') order by date desc;')
entries = cur.fetchall()
return render_template('dashboard2.html', entries=entries)
```

Template:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
{{ entry.date }}  ---  {{ entry.temperature }}
{% endfor %}
```

Result is:

```
2013-04-08 21:26:22 --- 22.31
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%s',date),temperature from temperatures where temperatures.date > datetime('now','-1hour', 'localtime') order by date desc;
```

gives(in sqlite console):

```
(...)
1365340231|22.56
1365340221|22.56
1365340210|22.5
1365340199|22.56
(...)
```

but:

```
cur = db.execute('select strftime(\'%s\',date),temperature from temperatures where temperatures.date > datetime(\'now\',\'-1hour\', \'localtime\') order by date desc;')
```

this select gives empty values in entry.date and expected values in entry.temperature in **flask** template:

```
 --- 22.31
```

---

I posted solution below.

Comment: Unrelated: remember that you can use both kinds of quotation interchangeably. If you'll use `""` for writing the SQL query, you won't have to escape `'` quote marks.

Comment: Which version of SQLite is that? Using `-1hour` modifier (without space between number and `hour`) I get `NULL` from `datetime()` function, while using `-1 hour` returns a date. I'm using SQLite 3.7.16.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas SQLite 3.6.22. Friend already helped me with problem. It looks like I made some mistakes with explaining problem. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, friend helped me with finding error:

Problem was that I tried to use value **entry.date** in my template, but but nothing was associated with date in entry.

Solution: "strftime('%s', date) **as date**, temperature ...", then result of strftime is put into entries.date as it should be.